# Getting pixel data from CGImageRef contains extra bytes?

Tags: ios, bitmap, core-graphics, cgimage

I'm looking at optimizing a routine that fetches the pixel data from a CGImage. The way this currently is done (very inefficiently) is to create a new CGContext, draw the CGImage into the context, and then get the data from the context.

I have the following optimized routine to handle this:

```
CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
uint8_t *pixelData = NULL;

CGDataProviderRef imageDataProvider = CGImageGetDataProvider(imageRef);
CFDataRef imageData = CGDataProviderCopyData(imageDataProvider);
pixelData = (uint8_t *)malloc(CFDataGetLength(imageData));
CFDataGetBytes(imageData, CFRangeMake(0, CFDataGetLength(imageData)), pixelData);
CFRelease(imageData);
```

This almost works. After viewing and comparing the hex dump of the pixel data obtained through both methods, I found that in the above case, there are 8 bytes of 0's every 6360 bytes. Otherwise, the data is identical. e.g.
[image]

And here is the comparison with the unoptimized version:
[image]

After the 8 bytes of 0's, the correct pixel data continues. Anyone know why this is happening?

UPDATE:
Here is the routine I am optimizing (the snipped code is just getting size info, and other non-important things; the relevant bit being the pixel data returned):

```
CGContextRef context = NULL;
CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;
CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedFirst;

// ... SNIP ...

context = CGBitmapContextCreate(...);
CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

// ... SNIP ...

CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, imageRef);
uint8_t *pixelData = (uint8_t *)CGBitmapContextGetData(context);

CGContextRelease(context);
```

Obviously this is an excessive amount of work just to get the underlying pixel data. Creating a context, then drawing into it. The first routine is between 5 - 10 times as fast. But as I pointed out, the pixel data returned by both routines are almost identical, except for the insertion of 8 zero-byte values every 6360 bytes in the optimized code (highlighted in the images).

Otherwise, everything else is the same -- color values, byte order, etc.

Comment: I'm unclear how you got these two different pixel buffers and what qualifies one as being "optimized" and the other "unoptimized". I'm unclear why you're going through this process you describe. Either more clearly describe how you got these two pixel buffers, or just tell us what you're trying to do.

Comment: @Rob See update above. I'm going through the process to get the underlying pixel data from a CGImage in order to pass it to a custom rendering engine that operates on individual pixels.

Comment: My point is that if you want the underlying pixel data for the image, you don't have to go through that round-tripping process. (That process, though, is useful when dealing with heterogenous image formats and you want to get it in a single consistent format.) In answer to why one has the extra bytes, I'd wager that `CGImageGetBytesPerRow` for the two will return different values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The bitmap data has padding at the end of each row of pixels, to round the number of bytes per row up to a larger value. (In this case, a multiple of 16 bytes.)

This padding is added to make it faster to process and draw the image.

You should use `CGImageGetBytesPerRow()` to find out how many bytes each row takes. Don't assume that it's the same as `CGImageGetWidth() * CGImageGetBitsPerPixel() / 8`; the bytes per row may be larger.

Keep in mind that the data behind an arbitrary `CGImage` may not be in the format that you expect. You cannot assume that all images are 32-bit-per-pixel ARGB with no padding. You should either use the CG functions to figure out what format the data might be, or redraw the image into a bitmap context that's in the exact format you expect.  The latter is typically much easier -- let CG do the conversions for you.

(You don't show what parameters you're passing to `CGBitmapContextCreate`. Are you calculating an exact `bytesPerRow` or are you passing in 0?  If you pass in 0, CG may add padding for you, and you may find that drawing into the context is faster.)

Comment: It does look like it's padding, and `CGImageGetBytesPerRow()` is 8 bytes larger than calculating according to the image's width. And yes, I know that CGImage may be in a variety of formats, but ARGB will be enforced. And drawing into a bitmap context is what it was doing already, and that's just way too inefficient for a method that is being called repeatedly.

Comment: I just spent the whole morning trying to find out what was going on. Thanks for this, upvoted.